# memq for lists and streams

Tags: functional-programming, scheme, racket

Could someone tell me what potential problems we would get from changing these two first functions dedicated to removing duplicates from a list to the last two that are for streams

```
(define (memq item x)
 (cond ((null? x ) #f)
  ((eq? item (car x )) x)
    (else (mem item (cdr x)))))


(define (r lst)
 (cond ((null? lst) '())
   ((not (memq (car lst ) (scdr lst)))
    (cons(car lst) (r (cdr lst))))
     (else (r ( cdr last)))))
```

Under we have the stream version, all I have done here as you can see is changing car,cons and cdr to stream versions. I read that this will have potential problems but I cannot see why.

```
(define (memq item x)
 (cond ((null? x ) #f)
  ((eq? item (stream-car x )) x)
    (else (memq item (stream-cdr x)))))


(define (r lst)
 (cond ((null? lst) '())
   ((not (memq (stream-car lst ) (stream-cdr lst)))
    (cons-stream (stream-car lst) (r (stream-cdr lst))))
     (else (r ( stream-cdr lst)))))
```

Comment: Where did you read this? Knowing that would certainly help make answers more on topic.

Comment: @amalloy I read this from a powerpoint slide from my university, it does not say anything more than what I wrote here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A big part of the point of streams is that they may potentially be infinite, because they are generated as needed. When the stream version of your `r` function is called on any infinite stream, it will never produce a single value. Can you see why this is?

Comment: Maybe because we cannot check infinite elements?

Comment: Indeed, but some other kinda of operations can perfectly reasonably be performed on streams. You can `map` an infinite stream, increasing each of its elements by one, for example. You get back another infinite stream, which you can consume one element at a time for as long as you like. What's the difference between `map` and your `r`?

Comment: hmm, so we can control the flow of the map, while r will just continue until the end of the stream?

Comment: The key is that `map` is "productive": it can produce an element after some finite amount of work. Your function is not. It can easily decide *not* to produce an element, but it can never finish reading the infinite stream to conclude that there are no duplicates.